# Select rows from table using tree order

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree

I have table witch contains fields: id, parent_id, name (etc.)

i want to order this table in "tree travel order" ie.

```
id  parent_id
1,  0
3,  1
5,  1

2,  0
8,  2

4,  0
9,  4
```

(...)

in short describe: take root node, append all children, take next root node append children etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By your description I assume you mean breadth-first order, which could be easly done using a WITH RECURSIVE query (PostgreSQL 8.4+):

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        node_name, id, parent_id, NULL::varchar AS parent_name 
    FROM foo 
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        node_name, f1.id, f1.parent_id, tree.node_name AS parent_name 
    FROM 
        tree 
        JOIN foo f1 ON f1.parent_id = tree.id
) 
SELECT node_name, empno, parent_id, node_name FROM tree;
```

You could also use depth-first order using the following SQL:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        node_name, id, parent_id, NULL::varchar AS parent_name, id::text AS path 
    FROM foo WHERE parent_id IS NULL 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        node_name, f1.id, f1.parent_id, tree.node_name AS parent_name, tree.path || '-' || f1.id::text AS path 
    FROM 
        tree 
        JOIN foo f1 ON f1.parent_id = tree.id
) 
SELECT node_name, empno, parent_id, node_name, path FROM tree ORDER BY path;
```

Comment: Thx for that, i was not aware of existing WITH queries in Postgres

Comment: I think we can not use UNION statement in WITH clause

Comment: Your solution for depth-first order won't work for id's with different number of digits.

Answer (score 5):

As noticed by *synergetic*, the solution for depth-first order provided by *Diogo Biazus* won't work for id's with different number of digits.

But you can use this solution instead, that uses arrays of integer :

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree 
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        node_name, id, parent_id, NULL::varchar AS parent_name, array[id] AS path 
    FROM foo WHERE parent_id IS NULL 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        node_name, f1.id, f1.parent_id, tree.node_name AS parent_name, tree.path || f1.id AS path 
    FROM 
        tree 
        JOIN foo f1 ON f1.parent_id = tree.id
) 
SELECT node_name, empno, parent_id, node_name, path FROM tree ORDER BY path;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the excellent [LTree](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/gist/ltree/) module, but you need to reorganise your data a bit.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id,parent_id
```

That should order my columns in the order there placed within the query.

Unless you mean GROUP the items, witch I think you do, then use

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id GROUP BY parent_id
```

And i also advise you to read this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: This will produce syntax error in Postgres (id field must be used in aggregate function), this is not MySQL :)

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry, I thought that would have worked under `postgres`, im not as good with it.

Comment: Would this work under psotgress `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id || id ASC, parent_id ASC` ?

Comment: this produces: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer || integer ; || is string catenation operator in postgres

Comment: This is what i was reading: maybe it would be better for you to take a look: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2007-08/msg00079.php

Comment: And also check: http://linuxtopia.org/online_books/database_guides/Practical_PostgreSQL_database/PostgreSQL_x5802_010.htm